# Recursion for cycle not increasing it's value before return statement

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Main2 {
    private static int[] arr = new int[3];
    private static int[] values = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        generateVariations(0);
    }

    private static void generateVariations(int index) {
        if (index == arr.length) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = index; i < values.length; i++) {
            arr[index] = values[i];
            swap(i, index);
            generateVariations(index + 1);
            swap(i, index);
        }

    }

    private static void swap(int i, int index) {
        int temp = values[i];
        values[i] = values[index];
        values[index] = temp;
    }
}
```

So in this code, the for loop in the `generateVariations` method doesn't increase the value of `i` until my code execution hits the `return` statement.  Why is this happening? I mean that `i` has the value of `index` as if the `i++` is absent, it only increases it self once a `return` statement is hit.

Comment: Why do you think it's not increasing? For me it seems like everything must work well

Comment: ye cuz i "stole" the example, coudn't figure it out on my own... and debugging didn't help it's why i asked, but Michael explained it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it - the `i++` will only be executed once the body of the for loop is completed. However, you are calling `generateVariations` recursively, i.e. before ever completing the first for body `generateVariations` is called again... and again... and again. Of course every call of `generateVariations` gets an ever larger `index` (since you increment in the call) - as such execution will hit the return statement eventually. Once this happens, the inner most for body (maybe you are 4 calls deep into `generateVariations`) will complete and finally increment **its** value of `i` and so forth.

Comment: thanks, i got that, but i seem to have 1 more question. The `return ` statement in recursive call, all it does is delete the first method from the call stack?

Comment: The `return` call will pop the inner most function call. Then the for body of the function which called the inner most one will continue operation.